# bitwise operations in python (or,and, |)

Tags: python-3.x, bitwise-operators

I am doing some and, or operations in python and I am getting a very different result. I am not able to understand the logic behind this.

```
input -> 22 & 1
output-> 0
input -> 22 & 21 
output-> 20
input -> 34 | 30
output ->62
input -> 2 | 9
output -> 11
```

Please assist me in understanding the logic
[Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnI7T.png)

Comment: As the name suggest, the operators are *bit-wise*. Use `bin` for each number to see their binary representation to aid your reasoning. For example, see `bin(22)` and `bin(1)` and convince yourself that there's no two bits that would be 1 in the same position for the two numbers.

Comment: That is pure teoretical question read all about it [Bitwise Operators] (https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)